# Verify identity of another process running on the same physical machine

Tags: linux, macos, security, unix, operating-system

I have a process A, which receives HTTP requests from a process B and accordingly performs some action. These actions are sensitive, so I have to ensure that A rejects any requests that come from processes other than B.

Is there any way at all to do this? One way I can think of is to use auth tokens the same way they're used for typical secure server-client communication. The problem is that traffic on loopback interface isn't secure and someone could read the token.

I don't necessarily have to use HTTP for passing messages, so perhaps there is some OS-specific function I could use?

Comment: Encryption keys?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Designing secure IPC is an interesting area of thought - I'm curious about why this is important to you. I would hope that if process A is handling any sensitive information, you have control over the machine on which it's running. If it's not, you might owe it to whoever that sensitive data is for/about to take a second to rethink your environment.

I think [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/176324) and the associated post in general on the infosec StackExchange gives a lot of good food for thought which I bet is also applicable to your situation.

I would also recommend using UNIX sockets as your base communication layer if you're dedicated to securing your same-machine IPC. But again, if you're in a situation where you really have to worry about this, you might want to focus on getting out of that situation instead.

Comment: From what I read on the internet, it seems like there is absolutely no way of protecting processes from malicious processes running with the same user privileges. Is that the case? 

As for what I'm trying to do - I'm writing a browser extension that can be controlled by a native application to automate webpages. It would be catastrophic if some malicious process took control of the extension. I guess I'll try securing it with existing browser APIs, I really don't want to involve a remote server.